# Hide store prices if not logged in - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, product-prices

I have 3 stores on the same website, and I would like for one of the stores, the prices do not show if the customer has not logged in. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Please install below module which is provide like this features. Store owner to hide the product price and add to cart button from guests or certain customer groups.

https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ProductAvailable

after install put below command via ssh.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

I hope its very helpful to you..

Comment: Thanks! But I can use this extension only in one store right?

Comment: No, Its working multi store.

Comment: I have 3 stores on my website, and I need to hide the prices for a single store, so this extension does not help me, right?

Comment: I tested its working with multi-store.

Comment: @Manu this extension is for all stores as Anas said. If you want to hide you pricing only for one store out of 3 as you specified then simply unselect all the groups from "Hide from Groups" for those specific store level.

Comment: Does this work in 2.35p

Comment: If so why can I not see after manual install Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Product Available?

Answer (score 0):

Does his work with 2.35p

If so manual install using ssh expanded the memory limit first check php ran ssh commands reindexed clean cache

Restarted admin but can not find even in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Product Available.

Was really good with 1.3.-1.7 Been I while since, so it would be good to find a solution